# How do you select a value from a list using a variable with an int value?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to create a program that converts denary to binary, and I'm doing it by finding the range its in (as in between which powers of 2), which can give me the number of digits. Then I find the remainder for the number divided by 2 the same number of times as the number of digits, and while in the loop, I added the values into a list. I'm then trying to extract the numbers one by one so that they can fit into a binary number, but it doesn't let me select a value with a variable like this:
    value = numbers_list[n]

If this doesn't work then how else can I extract the numbers from the list one by one??

This is my code:

```
number = int(input("Choose a positive denary number"))
while number != int and number < 0:
    number = int(input("Choose a positive denary number"))

if number == 0:
    print("The converted value is 0")

x = 0

while True:
    value1 = 2**x
    if number <= value1:
        break
    x += 1

digits = x + 1

digits_real = digits

numbers_list = []

while digits != 0:
    result = number%2
    number = number//2
    numbers_list.append(result)
    digits -= 1

print(numbers_list)

numbers_list = numbers_list.reverse()

n = 0
y = digits_real - 1
final = 0

for i in range(digits_real):  
    value = numbers_list[n]
    final += value*(10**y)
    n += 1
    y -= 1

print(final)
```

What happened when I ran it:

Choose a positive denary number128
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Pei-Jen/Desktop/test.py", line 38, in 
    value = numbers_list[n]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `numbers_list = numbers_list.reverse()` to `numbers_list.reverse()`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @LiuChang, `numbers_list.reverse()` will reverse the list in-place and return `None`, it is a member function of the built-in type `list`, `list.sort()` is similar. And the built-in function `reversed` and `sorted` will return a new list reversed, sorted respectively if you pass a list instance as a parameter.